# multiple touch button to work after two clicks

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton

hello i am making a game where it takes two clicks to break a block using a uibutton and ibaction how can i implement a code in my IBaction to basically work after being clicked twice and not once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of how many times each UIButton has been pressed somehow. Here are two ideas of how you might do that:

1) Assuming you have an array of UIButtons because you have multiple blocks, keep an array of integers that represent how many times each respective button has been tapped.

2) You could subclass UIButton into something like CountTrackingButton which has an int property `timesPressed`

Option 1 is probably easier to implement into your current code, but option 2 might be cleaner and better if you want to reuse it.

Finally, your IBAction needs to the following: 1) increment the count (either in the array or on your button subclass), 2) if that count is >= 2, break the block, else return.

Comment: thanks man! could you possibly provide an example code of the second idea you showed :D